# How to disable Compiling from the WED Editor in AccuTerm

Tags: multivalue, pick, jbase

We are using jBASE 5.6 multivalue database. Is there a way to disable the fact that AccuTerm's WED Editor has the ability to compile programs in the underlying MultiValue database? We are running into an issue where the user is accidentally compiling records instead of programs, which creates corrupt records in the datafiles.

I believe there is also a shortcut key (Function Key) that is in use. Help!

Comment: Hi Welcome to stackoverflow. it would be great if you would read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first before posting. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Nico, what was wrong with my question? I should have asked a question-format in the title, but other than that, any help?

Answer (score 1):

As of AccuTerm Release 7.3a there is no explicit option to disable the compile shortcut in the AccuTerm wED (Windows Editor). There are two techniques you can apply, however, that will work:

1. Change the *Compile* command to a single space

   - Open the **wED**
   - Click on the **Tools** menu at the top
   - Click on **Settings**
   - Click on the **Tools** tab
   - In the **Compile** section, change the text in the **Command** input from *BASIC* to a single space. Note that some flavors of PICK use *BASIC* as the compilation command whereas others use *COMPILE*. Since you are running jBASE, *BASIC* applies in this instance but for others such as D3 the command to replace is *COMPILE*.
2. It is possible to write a wrapper program to handle compilation for you, which when cataloged could be called from this same **Command** input. That program could be written to decide whether or not the target record exists in a code file or a data file and then compile or skip, respectively. Due to the fact that PICK systems do not have a file type specification, this logic would be somewhat unique to your environment depending on your practices. Common practice is to denote code files as *BP* files, i.e. *FileNameBP* or *FileName.BP* but again it would depend on your implementation.

For the record, a request to have a more formal option for disabling the *Compile* command has been submitted to the AccuTerm development team for consideration in the next major release.

Comment: Thanks @MikeWright! This was exactly what I was looking for, since clearing out the field of the "Compile" set it back to something else (i.e., it has to have something in there)